# how to enforce twitter account to follow a blog

Tags: php, twitter, wordpress, twitter-oauth

I am very much new to wordpress. I have created a blog.Now the thing I want is to make some mechanism like 
Whenever I add new post then it will generate a tweet to all those users who are following my account.
I find the [WP to twitter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-to-twitter/) but it is not the thing which I am looking for.Using this plugin , I can only tweet to my account but I want to tweet all subscribers account and I don't know their credentials.
So experts please guide me that how can I achieve this functionality that 
Some person follow my blog and get tweet on every new post.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't.  Automating tweets to accounts other than your own violates Twitter's policies.

Sorry, but you can see why Twitter doesn't want tweet mentioning automated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. once you set-up all informations in Setting your posts will automatically get posted to your account.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-to-twitter/